# Share hash across Perl scripts

Tags: perl, hash, sharing

Is it possible to share a hash created by a Perl script by another Perl script on a Linux machine ?

```
./hash_script.pl # Creates a hash after parsing a file
                 # Takes several minutes and hash consumes 4Gb of memory

./script1.pl # Reads hash

./script2.pl # Reads hash
```

I want to create the hash once and use it many times,whenever `script1.pl` and `script2.pl` are run.

Comment: What about this http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/SharedMem.html ?

Answer (score 2):

If your hash_script script dumps its hash into a file somewhere (using Data::Dumper or some other means), you can load that hash in a subsequent script with `do`.

In script1/script2:

```
our %sharedhash; #whatever name the hash has in the dumped file
do 'hash_dump_file.txt' or die "Couldn't read hash: $@";

print $sharedhash{stuff};
```

Comment: Will it be any different than embedding hash create function in `script1.pl` and `script2.pl` ?

Comment: It will be as if you just typed out the resulting hash explicitly inside script1/script2. I'm assuming that the hash takes a long time to generate due to running some long running computation and then storing the results in a hash. If it takes several minutes to generate because you have 100 million dumb keys, than this may not help that much.

Comment: Its about 24 million easy to map "dumb" key-value pairs. So I don't think this will help. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the Perl module [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html). Storable can take any data structure and store it onto a disk.

```
use Storable;  # It automatically imports all functions. Grrr...

...

store \%hash, $file_name;
```

However, if this is a 4Gb file, it probably is way too big to be used effectively for a Perl hash. This is why other posts are recommending you to use SQL or a [NoSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20081214/368630). A hash would have to keep the entire file in memory and attempt to manipulate it. A SQL or NoSQL database could pull up the file that's required.

However, try `Storable`, and see how long it takes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say why you need such a big hash in memory, but probably use of some NoSQL database would be more suitable.

Take a look at [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).

Comment: I am looking up lot of information from the file. Storing it as a hash makes it faster.

Comment: How often the file changes?

Comment: Then I would definitely recommend transform content of file to some key-value store with suitable structure.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating package and loading it in other scripts? But if it's size is about 4Gb, it's too much for this approach. Next solution could be memcached or something like that.
Could you write other information about your hash? How are you using it in the other two scripts?

Answer (score 0):

[dbmopen](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/dbmopen.html) / dbmclose allows you to have a normal hash implemented by means of a file on your drive. I've never tried reading a DBM from a different script than the one that created it, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.